# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oSavedState' of undefined with yadcf and DataTable in Bootbox

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, bootbox, yadcf

I have a bootbox dialog for a user to select templates. The template list is loaded via ajax in DataTables and yadcf is added for fancy filtering. First open of the dialog works flawlessly, close the dialog and open it again and it fails in the yadcf library on

```
function initColReorder2(settingsDt, table_selector_jq_friendly)
```

I have created an example illustrating this https://jsfiddle.net/mrcrbrown/7gtps9n5/11/ Click the button to open the dialog, close the dialog with the X and then attempt to open it again.

I noticed the failure occurs before the datatables goes to get the data. I should be able to open and close the dialog as many times as I like as a user.

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359479/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-osavedstate-of-undefined-with-yadcf-a which has the same error in the same place but no answer or example posted.

Comment: Thanks for the test case, seen the error and will fix it soon hopefully

Comment: Great thanks Daniel, wasn't sure if an issue or something relating to bootbox

Comment: In progress... https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/772

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go grab [0.9.0.beta.5](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/fb44de31cd3d995f9d94599d4b1fb05d8d4c45c1/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)  it works now, see [live sample](https://jsfiddle.net/7gtps9n5/15/).

```
.
```

Comment: worked a treat, thanks for tracking that down Daniel. Great job on the plugin

Comment: @iamchriswick please open an issue with link to a test case, link that test case to my [local js file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55621125/yadcf/war14/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)